# Show directly that if $\{s_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence then so is $\{|s_n|\}$. Conclude that $\{|s_n|\}$ converges whenever $\{s_n\}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Show directly that if $\{s_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence then so is $\{|s_n|\}$. From this conclude that $\{|s_n|\}$ converges whenever $\{s_n\}$ converges.

Let $\{s_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then by definition, for any given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $m>0$ such that $|s_n-s_m|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq m$.
Then we have $$||s_n|-|s_m||\leq|s_n-s_m|$$
Therefore, from the definition 
$$||s_n|-|s_m||\leq|s_n-s_m|<\varepsilon$$
for all $n\geq m$. Hence, $\{|s_n|\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

And then to prove that convergence of $\{s_n\}$ implies the convergence of $\{|s_n|\}$:

Let $\varepsilon>0$. If $\{s_n\}$ converges to $L$, then there exists $N$ such that $|s_n-L|<\varepsilon$, whenever $n\geq N$. Hence, for $n\geq N$, we have $||s_n|-L|\leq |s_n-L|<\varepsilon$. Thus $\{|s_n|\}$ converges to $|L|$.

That's how I proved but I'm not sure if I possibly made some mistakes or missed some steps!?

Comment: Hint: Reverse triangle inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality). From there, it suffices to show that every Cauchy sequence converges (if you haven't shown that already).

Comment: Your proof is close to being correct but your definition of a sequence being Cauchy is not. Instead of $n\geq m$, it should be $\forall n,m \geq M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The idea is that, starting at some index, any two numbers in that sequence are "close enough" to each other, how close? epsilon-close!

Answer (score 2):

If we are dealing with a **complete** metric space, we know that every Cauchy sequence is convergent to a limit in that metric space. So if you prove that the sequence is $\{|s_n| \}$ is Cauchy, indeed by using the reverse triangle inequality, we automatically get that it is a convergent sequence.